# QT clear widget contents

Tags: c++, qt

I have QWidget renameWidget which is referred to as ui->renameWidget. Within this, I have a QVBoxLayout *renamebox and within this I have several labels and textedits.

What I need to happen is that when I hit a button to submit these textedits, I need everything within the QWidget to be deleted. This will give the effect of the box being emptied or cleared.

I've tried to just delete the vboxlayout and I've also tried this:

```
qDeleteAll(ui->renameWidget->findChildren<QVBoxLayout *>());
```

Nothing has worked, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
 qDeleteAll(ui->renamebox->findChildren<QLabel *>());
 qDeleteAll(ui->renamebox->findChildren<QTextEdit *>());
```

Although it's typically better to call deleteLater on most QObject based classes because it allows the objects to be cleaned up in the next pass through the event loop, not in the middle of an event being processed

Comment: You really should replace the qDeleteAll with a loop that calls deleteLater on all the children found though

Answer (score 1):

`qDeleteAll(ui->renamebox->children());` would delete all children.